# Sharepoint 2010 Using JavaScript to set the Body #S4-Workflow

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am hoping someone might be able to help. I am trying to change the 'Body #s4-workflow" height to auto when the user is on an iPhone or iPad. This is a Sharepoint 2010 site. I have put the following code into the head section of the Master page but it does not change the height. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
        document.getElementById("body #s4-workspace").style.Height = "auto !important";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it an onload function on a specific page and seeing if it will work?

I would attempt to make it an onload function and putting it into just a basic content editor on a page. If it works on that page after loading, it's probably due to Sp.js loading up after your script is being ran and thus writing over it.

Comment: That makes sense. I Have just tried the following code but it doesn't work either. Is it possible set the script to manually run after the sp.js loads?                  <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('body #s4-workspace').onload = function(){
 if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
    this.style.Height = "auto !important"; 
  }
</script>

Comment: That script you just wrote should be producing errors. You want something more along the lines of
document.onload = function setAutoWidth(){ your code}

That will run the function setAutoWidth once the document is loaded up

Sorry for not being much help, I'll return to this later when I"m not on a phone

Comment: no problem. You have been a great help so far. This is what I've got at the moment `<script type="text/javascript">
document.onload = function setAutoHeight(){ 
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){
    document.getElementById('body #s4-workspace').style.Height = "auto !important"; 
  }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setAutoHeight");
</script> </head>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out if anyone needs something like this in future. The following script runs after everything else has stopped running using "_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push", so the sp.js and the sp.ribbon.js do not override the css:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setAutoHeight() {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
        document.getElementById('body #s4-workspace').style.Height = "auto !important";
    } 
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setAutoHeight");
```